# Javascript animations moving a DOM element up (pure js)

Tags: javascript, function, animation, setinterval

I have two rectangles one blue, one green (the green is hidden by overflow). I am trying to make the green rectangle move up until it reaches the top of the blue rectangle when a button is clicked. I am quite new to Javascript and don't know where I am going wrong. The thought process behind the javascript is that I take the element and say if its position gets the top of the container then stop the function otherwise increment it from the bottom so that it moves up.

My code looks like this:

```
CSS


body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container{
    position: relative;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
#fullLoad{
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#loader{
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    top: 600px;


}
#btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 362px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: gold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #424242;

}

    HTML


<div id="container">

    <div id="fullLoad">

        <div id="loader"></div>

    </div>

    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Go !" onclick="load()">

</div>







    Javascript

function load() {
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader"); 
    var pos = 600;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 0) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++; 
            loader.style.bottom = pos + 'px'; 

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change

```
pos++;
loader.style.bottom = pos + 'px';
```

to

```
pos--; 
loader.style.top = pos + 'px';
```

Because you are starting at 600px from the top and you want to reach 0.

Proof:

```js
function load() {
    var loader = document.getElementById("loader"); 
    var pos = 600;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
    function frame() {
        if (pos == 0) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos--; 
            loader.style.top = pos + 'px'; 

        }
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
#container{
    position: relative;
    background-color: brown;
    height: 800px;
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 75px; 
}
#fullLoad{
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: blue;
    left: 300px;
    top: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
#loader{
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    top: 600px;
}
#btn{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 362px;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: gold;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    color: #424242;

}
```

```html
<div id="container">

    <div id="fullLoad">

        <div id="loader"></div>

    </div>

    <input id="btn" type="button" value="Go !" onclick="load()">

</div>
```